# Html- how to set background image

Tags: html

I want to set up an image as the background image of my webpage. But the source image height and width is very small. I want the source image to expand and fit to size of the screen. Give me the tags for doing this.

Comment: This would result in a very strange result. But have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973374/css3-how-to-expand-an-image-with-height-auto-for-a-few-pixels) SO question. Or do you want to repeat your image? You should also add a minimal code example to your question.

Answer (score -1):

These are the tags:

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need both the markup (what you've called tags), as well as the necessary css to get that done. I always refer to the post [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) when doing this on my own projects.